# Access JSon array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have my JSon output like this

```
Array ( 
    [status] => 1 
    [count] => 1 
    [message] => 
    [result] => Array ( 
        [User_Id] => 11 
        [Referral_Code] => xxxxx 
    ) 
    [resultList] => null
)
```

How do I access the referral_code object?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);` and this will make an associative array

Comment: that ain't a JSON string, its an array

Comment: You know how to access arrays in PHP dont you? `echo $array['result']['Referal_code']`

Comment: Hi Aayush

I am using this code

$get_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

when I print $get_response I get that array.

Answer (score 0):

If you name the array you showed `$sourceArray` you can do:

```
$sourceArray['result']['Referral_Code']
```

Comment: LOL Snap, this time its a tie

Comment: I tried this $sourceArray['result']['Referral_Code'] and its blank

Comment: @NarayanSrivathsan Show what appears on screen when you do `var_dump(PUT YOUR DATA HERE)`